# How to clip border partially with CSS (or SVG)?

Tags: css, svg, border, clip

I want to clip border of `div` which have some `border-radius` to imitate how timer expires.
But can't find any way to do it except like with `clip-path: polygon(...)`
But building custom polygon seems like really hard way to control border length.

Is there some simpler/ more elegant way to do it with CSS (or maybe SVG)?
Here is image of desirable result with few states ⇩⇩

[image: border clip]

Comment: SVG - and `stroke-dash-array`

Comment: https://medium.com/@pppped/how-to-code-a-responsive-circular-percentage-chart-with-svg-and-css-3632f8cd7705

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for directions! seems like combination of `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` will do the work. I will try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### pure svg

The effect of drawing a line is achieved using the attribute of the line `stroke-dashoffset`, which is an indent from the beginning of the line.

The line is hidden when `stroke-dashoffset` has a maximum value and is fully visible when`stroke-dashoffset = "0"`

Therefore, changing the value of `stroke-dashoffset` from max to zero, we get the effect of drawing the line.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="map_line_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >

    <rect x="50" y="100" width="200" height="100" rx="50" fill="#E0E9F6" stroke-width="4"  stroke="grey" stroke-dashoffset="600" stroke-dasharray="600">
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="1s" from="600" to="0" dur="7s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </rect>

</svg>
```

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for. Also, I found useful to know `stroke-dasharray` length. It can be get with js function 
`rect.getTotalLength()`

Comment: @Jamland  Thank you! If you wait a bit, I'll make a second version of CSS with a more detailed description

Comment: Any way to implement the same thing in React? And how to find the length of the SVG?

Comment: @georgekrax Calculating path length https://jsfiddle.net/mzy2wt91/

Comment: @Alexandr_TT So in React, I should do that with Refs?

Comment: @georgekrax Unfortunately I am not working with react Therefore, you need to ask a question to someone else.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

### CSS+SVG

This example is exactly the same as the first example, but the styles of the display style are transferred to an external stylesheet. More information on the drawing technique can be found here - **Chris Coyier** - [stroke-dashoffset](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dashoffset/)

You correctly noticed that the length of the line can be calculated using the JS method - `getTotalLength ()`

Here is an example of a script that prints the length of the path for figures drawn with `path`:

```js
<script>
  function TotalLength(){
   var path = document.querySelector('#check');
   var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
    alert("Path length - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

*Below is a complete example of animation:*

```css
#rect1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 600;
  stroke-dashoffset: 600;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 600;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
} 
#rect1 {
fill:#E0E9F6;
stroke-width:4;  
stroke:grey;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="map_line_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >

    <rect id="rect1" x="50" y="100" width="200" height="100" rx="50"  />
</svg>
```

If you need an animation of the movement of the line in one direction, replace the `alternate` with `forwards`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not need to animate the offset in this case. In the case of passing through the zero point as well as if you want to start not from the zero point problems may arise.
I would use 2 parameters - the stroke length and the stroke space, like:

```
<animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0 600" to="600 0" />
```